# In Linux/Bash how do I substitute //<newline> for a null character?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, sed

For example:

```
stat --format="%s %W %Y %X %Z %n//" * | sed "s/\/\/$/\x0/"
```

Is wrong because it still emits the newline.

- PS: I'm sure this question is very basic but somehow I didn't immediately determine an answer.

Comment: Regex: `(?<!\\)((?:\\\\)*)//(?:\r?\n)`. Replace with $1.

Answer (score 2):

No need to do a substitution after-the-fact; use `--printf` instead of `--format` and you won't get the newline in the first place, so you can request exactly the output format you want:

```
stat --printf='%s %W %Y %X %Z %n\0' *
```

However, if you had a version of `stat` that didn't support this, or your real program is something different, you might consider...

```
while IFS= read -r result; do
  case $result in
    *//) printf '%s\0' "${result%//}";;
    *)   printf '%s\n' "$result";;
  esac
done < <(stat --format="%s %W %Y %X %Z %n//" *)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

`stat --format="%s %W %Y %X %Z %n//" * | tr -d "\/\/\n"`